# How to find data in an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of arrays, I know it is not practical but the component I use renders (using React.js) data only as an array of arrays I delete some element of this array in a backend (Firestore) and I need to delete the data from this array on frontend.
The array:

```
const myData = [
  ["2020-09-14", "15:00", "60", "Info", "April Tucker", "Other", "no"],
  ["2020-09-14", "2:00", "50", "Text", "April Tucker", "Other", "yes"]
]
```

When I delete the data in backend I get the data I deleted as a change.doc.data(). Then I am trying to find the index of the deleted data in the myData state.

```
  if (change.type === 'removed') {
          console.log('Removed data: ', change.doc.data())
          const index = myData.indexOf(
            (element) =>
              element[0] == change.doc.data()[0] &&
              element[1] == change.doc.data()[1] &&
              element[2] == change.doc.data()[2] &&
              element[3] == change.doc.data()[3] &&
              element[4] == change.doc.data()[4] &&
              element[5] == change.doc.data()[5] &&
              element[6] == change.doc.data()[6]
          )
          console.log(index)
          mydata.splice(index, 1)
       
        }
```

This doesn't work, returning the index -1. I also tried mapping over the myData array, but my approach was not successful.

Comment: Your logic is... odd? `indexOf` finds the array index of "some thing", but you're passing in an arrow function, which, since you just defined it and so it's a new handle, is guaranteed not in your array. Having said that, what are your doing in that arrow function? (why use `==` instead of `===`? Why only test seven elements? Why do this as separate steps instead of using a dedicated array comparison function? etc)

Comment: So, how would you do it the best way?

Comment: take a look at https://medium.com/better-programming/check-if-an-array-is-within-a-2d-array-using-javascript-c534d96cb269

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like there is exactly what I need. 

Comment: Hello @JavaMan Your comment helped. I encourage you to post this as an answer.

Comment: @MrTech I'm glad I could help you, I've posted the part which is in my opinion the most relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at this [site](https://medium.com/better-programming/check-if-an-array-is-within-a-2d-array-using-javascript-c534d96cb269)

Especially at the following method which should get you started:

```
function arrayAlreadyHasArray(arr, subarr){
    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        let checker = false
        for(var j = 0; j<arr[i].length; j++){
            if(arr[i][j] === subarr[j]){
                checker = true
            } else {
                checker = false
                break;
            }
        }
        if (checker){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: The link had been already shared in the comments section above! But thank you.

Comment: @radmin1 yeah the link was posted by me ;)